# Инициалиация static полей в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, static

Unity не позволяет инициализировать статические переменные через инспектор. Есть ли какие-то способы заменить статические переменные?

Единственное условие: переменную можно читать из всех объектов класса, а задавать только через инспектор. Единственный способ проинициализировать static поле, который я нашёл это создать специальный gameObject для этого:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

    public class StaticInit : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public TileBase[] Acceptable; // Переменная из инспектора
        void Start()
        {
            TilemapSpawner.Acceptable = Acceptable; // Та самая статическая переменная

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Но Unity при этом жалуется на null.

Answer (score 1):

Через **Custom Editor** можно все.

```
public class StaticInit : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int Test;
}
```

---

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(StaticInit))]

public class StaticInitEditor : Editor {
    private StaticInit _target;

    private void OnEnable () {
        _target = (StaticInit)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI () {
        _target.Test = EditorGUILayout.IntField("My Static Value", _target.Test);
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }
}
```